# 403 Forbidden Redirect To Homepage

Tags: php, redirect, nginx

I am trying to redirect a **403 Forbidden** request to the homepage of our website (index.php). An example URL that is receiving a 403 error message is this URL: *https://www.acme.com/dr/mellow/*. I tried adding the following line to my configuration file: `error_page 403 /index.php;`. When I did that, I no longer receive the 403 Forbidden message, I just receive a blank white page. I simply would like to redirect to `/index.php`. I am currently running an NGINX server. Here is my configuration file:

```
server {
    server_name acme.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.acme.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.acme.com;

    #BEGIN SSL
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/acme.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/acme.com.key;

    # Makes for the most secure connections
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:!aNULL;
    #END SSL

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html $uri.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 403 =200 /index.php;
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    ##BEGIN ALLOWING LARGE UPLOADS##
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    ## BEGIN CACHING SETTINGS ##
    # Media: images, icons, video, audio, fonts, HTC
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|woff)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # CSS and Javascript
    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
    ## END CACHING SETTINGS ##
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `error_page 403 =200 /index.php;` or within `location` block?

Comment: @revo I added your code and that works for HTTPS request but I am still getting a blank white page on HTTP request. I have updated my original post to show my most up to date code. Any suggestions on how to get this to work on HTTP as well?